# Use assert for control flow

Tags: python, exception, control-flow

I am trying to check if a word has a trailing semicolon. I have the position of the word within a long string, and I want to check if the character at the position `start of word + length of word` is a `:`. It can be that the word is the last word in the string, and therefore trying to get the next char will raise an `IndexException`

I have three ideas:

**1) Check that we are not at the end of the string, and then check that it is not semicolon**

```
semicolon_pos = pos_word + len(word) # Possible position
if semicolon_pos < len(long_string) and long_string[semicolon_pos] == ':':
    # do something...
else:
    # do something else
```

Not what it is normally considered pythonic

**2) Try-except the semicolon extraction and the equality for the semicolon**

```
semicolon_pos = pos_word + len(word) # Possible position
try:
   if long_string[semicolon_pos] == ':':
      # Do something
   else:
      # do something else (which is the same as in the except clause)

except IndexError:
    # do something else
```

Looks a little bit weird, to extract and then nested. And I have to do a little trick to avoid the code duplication

**3) Try-except the semicolon extraction and an assertion to make sure it is a semicolon**

```
semicolon_pos = pos_word + len(word) # Possible position
try:
    assert long_string[semicolon_pos] == ':'
    # do something
except (IndexError, AssertionError):
    # do something else
```

Structure is flatter and it is easily read, but I have the feeling that is abusing exceptions usage.

What do the python folks say?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I overwrote a comment. I was editing myself too. Sorry!

Comment: Looks quite pythonic to me.  You might consider asking this in code review.  The important thing is to make clear what your intentions are, so you might want to wrap it in a function `colon_follows_word`.

Comment: @daveoncode, I dont have a string to apply `.endswith(':')`. I have a word (which does not include the colon), and I want to check if the next char is a colon.

Comment: ok… I don't know what you are doing, but probably I would use a regex :)

Comment: Too complex for string manipulation, too simple for regexs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use a slice as a subscript. Slices don't throw IndexError:

```
semicolon_pos = pos_word + len(word) # Possible position
if long_string[semicolon_pos:semicolon_pos+1] == ':':
   # Do something
else:
   # do something else
```

Comment: Since you gave first this idea, I'll mark it as the right one. It timeit'ed and is more efficient than checking the length and then comparing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely a misuse of assertions. Reason: assertions aren't even executed when the code is run with the `-O` flag.

The recommended way to use assertions is to check for "impossible" conditions resulting from a mistake in the algorithm (post-conditions). For pre-conditions and program logic, one should use ordinary exceptions.

Comment: Probably the most interesting I've learnt here, although just being a partial answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`(string[index] if index < len(string) else None) == ':'`

Comment: This is less efficient than slicing

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier this way:

```
#considering mylongstring contains the word
#+1 for the possible colon
mylongstring[:pos_word + len(word) + 1].endswith(':')
```

Or, if the long string is very long you don't want to copy too much:

```
mylongstring[pos_word:pos_word + len(word) + 1][-1] == ':'
```

Comment: I don't know how long 'mylongstring' is, but if it is actually long then could be taking a very long slice out of it just to check the last character. It is probably going to be better to just extract the one character you want to test.

Comment: It the average case is not very long, but I would like to be as efficient as possbiel. The slicing between that char and the next looks pretty good to me. I would compare directly to ':' instead of `endswith`.

Comment: @ikaros45 : Indeed:

In [1]: timeit -n 100000 a.endswith(":")
100000 loops, best of 3: 159 ns per loop

In [2]: timeit -n 100000 a[-1]==":"
100000 loops, best of 3: 78.6 ns per loop