# How to implement decorator with two arfument function

Tags: python

I haven't use decorator before but now I need to implement some repitable tests that compare some lists of data and I want to use less code for this. I whant to have a function that compares list of data from two data sets.

```
 def compare(a,b):
    for j, c in zip(a, b):
        try:
            assert j == c
        except AssertionError:
            raise AssertionError(f"\n{a} arr1: {j}\n{b} arr2:  {c}")
```

And this is two lists:

```
arr1 = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
arr2 = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
```

I'm creating decorator:

```
def decor(func):
    def comp(a,b):
        for j, c in zip(a, b):
            try:
                assert j == c
            except AssertionError:
                raise AssertionError(f"\n{a}: {j}\n{b}:  {c}")
            func()
    return comp
```

Then defining method with two lists:

```
@decor
def lists():
    arr1 = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
    arr2 = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
    return arr1, arr2
```

But I'm getting an error and don't know how to set expected arguments:

`TypeError: comp() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'`

Comment: By the way - [don't use `assert` for control-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133264/12299000).

Comment: You are getting the error because the inner function of the decorator expects 2 arguments but `list` has no arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your function will return two lists and you *must* do this with a decorator, I suggest we keep your `compare(a,b)` function separate for the time being to keep it simple. Then in the decorator:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        a, b = func(*a, **kw)
        compare(a,b)
        return a, b
    return wrapper
```